# How to define attribute aliased name to a c++ function?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

in my cpp file i have the following:

```
int A()
{
}
void B_A() __attribute__((alias ("A")));
```

and i am getting the error:
B_A() aliased to undefined symbol A; 
however, as u can notice, A is being defined just before that.

so whats the problem!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> In C++, the mangled name for the target must be used.

So, you need the mangled name of `A`, or you need to give `A` C linkage so its name doesn't get mangled in the first place.